# I follow react-navigation docs, but it doesn't work, Mainly "react-native-screens"

Tags: react-native

this is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "awesomeproject1",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "a": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.8",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "react": "16.8.1",
    "react-native": "0.61.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.9.0",
    "react-native-tab-navigator": "^0.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
    "jest": "^24.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.51.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

when `npm run a`,

```
PS I:\loan> npm run a

> awesomeproject1@0.0.1 a I:\loan
> react-native run-android

info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 971 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info Starting JS server...
info Installing the app...

> Task :react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
62 actionable tasks: 18 executed, 44 up-to-date
e: I:\loan\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt: (20, 38): Unresolved reference: ReactTypefaceUtils 
e: I:\loan\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt: (206, 37): Unresolved reference: ReactTypefaceUtils
e: I:\loan\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt: (325, 28): Unresolved reference: ReactTypefaceUtils

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
e: I:\loan\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt: (20, 38): Unresolved reference: ReactTypefaceUtils
e: I:\loan\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt: (206, 37): Unresolved reference: ReactTypefaceUtils
e: I:\loan\node_modules\react-native-screens\android\src\main\java\com\swmansion\rnscreens\ScreenStackHeaderConfig.kt: (325, 28): Unresolved reference: ReactTypefaceUtils

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 41s

    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:790:11)
    at execFileSync (child_process.js:827:15)
    at runOnAllDevices (I:\loan\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:39)
    at buildAndRun (I:\loan\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:179:41)
    at I:\loan\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\index.js:133:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (I:\loan\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:182:9)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! awesomeproject1@0.0.1 a: `react-native run-android`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the awesomeproject1@0.0.1 a script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Yiming\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-23T09_11_23_054Z-debug.log
```

**Please!!!How to solve it...**

this is build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! React Native build errors can be really confusing for everyone. I Would suggest adding a link to the project for this kind of errors. Even tho this is not an answer but you could try a couple of things: try changing your kotlinVersion to `kotlinVersion = "1.3.72"` in your Gradle file. Or try adding this dependency to your Gradle build file `implementation "com.onfido.sdk.capture:onfido-capture-sdk-core:4.2.0"`. And maybe the thing to check first, make sure everything is up-to-date within your Android development environment.

Answer (score 0):

this is right version,

```
 {
      "name": "awesomeproject1",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "a": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.6",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.15",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.2",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "5.x",
        "i": "^0.3.7",
        "npm": "^8.1.4",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "react": "16.8.1",
        "react-native": "0.61.3",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.7.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.0-beta.1",
        "react-native-screens": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.5.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.5.0",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.3",
        "babel-jest": "^24.1.0",
        "jest": "^24.1.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.51.1",
        "react-test-renderer": "16.8.1"
      },
      "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native"
      }
    }
```